# Build a dataframe from a dict with specified labels from a txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i want to make a dataframe with defined labels. Dont know how to tell panda to take the labels from the list. Hope someone can help

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = []
thislist = []

thislist = ["A","D"]
thisdict =  {
             "A": [1, 2, 3],
             "B": [4, 5, 6],
             "C": [7, 8, 9],
             "D": [7, 8, 9]
            }

df = pd.DataFrame(data= thisdict[thislist])  # <- here is my problem
```

I want to get this:

```
df = A   D
     1   7
     2   8
     3   9
```

Comment: a way around it is to build the dataframe using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` and then just slice for the columns you want `df = df['A','D']`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict)[thislist]
print(df)
   A  D
0  1  7
1  2  8
2  3  9
```

We could also use [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict).drop(columns = ['B','C'])
```

or [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict).reindex(columns = thislist)
```

or [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict).filter(items=thislist)
```

We can also use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to filter `thisdict.items()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(filter(lambda item: item[0] in thislist, thisdict.items())))
print(df)
   A  D
0  1  7
1  2  8
2  3  9
```

I think this answer is completed with the solution of **@anky_91**

Finally, I recommend you see [`how to index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, use `.loc[]` with the dataframe constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict).loc[:,thislist]

print(df)
   A  D
0  1  7
1  2  8
2  3  9
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `dict` comprehension to create a new dictionary that is a subset of your original so you only construct the DataFrame you care about.

```
pd.DataFrame({x: thisdict[x] for x in thislist})
   A  D
0  1  7
1  2  8
2  3  9
```

If you want to deal with the possibility of missing Keys, add some logic so it's similar to `reindex`

```
pd.DataFrame({x: thisdict[x] if x in thisdict.keys() else np.NaN for x in thislist})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict)
df[['A', 'D']]
```

Answer (score 1):

another alternative for your input:

```
thislist = ["A","D"]
thisdict =  {
             "A": [1, 2, 3],
             "B": [4, 5, 6],
             "C": [7, 8, 9],
             "D": [7, 8, 9]
            }

df = pd.DataFrame(thisdict)
```

and than simply remove your columns  not in thelist (you can do it directly from the df or aggregate them):

```
remove_columns = []
for c in df.columns:
    if c not in thislist:
        remove_columns.append(c)
```

and remove it:

```
df.drop(columns=remove_columns, inplace=True)
```